# winforms designer hand code bring to front

Tags: c#, winforms, vb6, windows-forms-designer, vb6-migration

I'm converting some VB6 forms to C# and have created an utility which generates C# designer files from the VB6 source files. It's going well, but I've ran into some trouble with ordering.

I have an option button and an updown beside each other and the right side of the option button is slightly overlapping the updown. I tried resizing the option button, but no usable size seems to leave the caption visible.

I've considered changing the option button to have a transparent background, but unfortunately the solution isn't viable for all of my forms.

However, what I think would definitely work is bringing the updown to the front or sending the option button to the back, but I can't figure out how to do this from within the designer code only.

How can I bring controls to the front or send them to the back from the designer code? If anyone has a different solution for having the caption visible I'm open for suggestions. It must be done from within the designer code only, as that is what my tool generates.

Comment: Be specific about what your question

Comment: The Z-order is determined by the order of the Controls.Add() calls inside the InitializeComponent() method.  Fixing that sounds incredibly unproductive, it won't be a simple line-by-line conversion anymore.  Just fix it with the designer after you converted the form(s).  And keep in mind that this problem already existing in the VB.NET code, so do it up front or look for a bug in your conversion code if it didn't have this problem.

Comment: utility my question is quite clear what I want to do...

Hans I do not want to fix anything in the designer afterwards because I am doing 500ish forms and I do not want to visually inspect all of them and fix things because that kind of defeats the purpose. I found this visual issue more by chance than anything and I'd like to fix it for all forms it may appear on, I don't know if it appears on others or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which controls are added to their parent determines the initial Z-order. The control added first will be in front of controls added later:

```
this.Controls.Add(updownButton);
this.Controls.Add(optionButton);
```

Comment: OK so this is good knowledge but it's going to be a huge pain to add them in a different order than the order they are written in the VB6 file so I'm really hoping to find another answer... If I don't get any other suggestions today then I'll have to make this one work somehow.

Comment: It took me a little while but I was actually able to implement this fix faster than I thought. I set it up to do the controls.add first for a list of types so I can add more later if I find anything else being overlapped. Thanks for the help, shame there isn't a more direct way to do this but I suppose you aren't really supposed to directly write designer files so can't complain too much I guess...

Comment: Good to hear you got things working. In the end it's all just code, the only complex part is keeping the designer happy. At our company we eventually even chose to remove all designer code and apply our own templates.